# php - Symfony2 form dynamic input text field fill depending on a selection

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have the following situation:

In the database there is a table with all the counties in a country and a second table which contains all the cities in the same contry. The city table has the columns:

```
- id
- name
- longitude
- latitude
- county - county id
```

on the page I have a form with:

```
- county select field - symfony entity field type
- city select field - symfony entity field type
- longitude input (text) field
- latitude input (text) field - let's ignore this field for the moment
```

So, when the user selects a county, the city field is filled with all the cities coresponding the selected county; then, when the user selects a city, the longitude field is filled with the city logitude database value.

Following this tutorial (http://aulatic.16mb.com/wordpress/2011/08/symfony2-dynamic-forms-an-event-driven-approach/) I have managed to deal with county selection and city filed dynamic replacing. But I can't seem to find how to fill a simple text value (in this case longitude) "symfony way".

I have tried to do it like

```
$refreshLongitude = function( $form, $city, $translator ){
    $form->add(
        'longitude',
        'text',
        array(
            'label' => $translator->trans( 'project.longitude' ),
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'class'=> 'form-control',
                'value' => function( \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $repository ) use ( $city ){
                    if( $city instanceof City ){
                        return $city->getLongitude();
                    }

                    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder( 'city' );

                    if( is_numeric( $city ) ){
                        $query->where( 'city.id = :city' )
                            ->setParameter( 'city', $city );
                    }
                    else{
                        $query->where( 'city.id = 2715' );
                    }

                    $city = $query->getSingleResult();

                    return $city->getLongitude();
                }
            )
        )
    );
};
```

but I am getting:
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Any ideea?

Comment: Your lambda function is being passed as the value. If you want to call it such that your return value is sent back as the value, then you need to do so. See `call_user_func`.

Comment: Sorry, I am not used with php closure and lambda functions. If I add value => call_user_func( function( \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $repository ) use ( $city ){}, ??? ), I do not know how to pass that repository as argument for lamda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, starting from phpisuber01 comment (many thanks), I have managed to outline the following code to dinamically fill a simple text field with certain database value in symfony2. I am not sure that this is the right way, but it works. Any more elegant way is welcomed.

```
$refreshLongitude = function( $form, $city, $translator, $em ){
    $form->add(
        'longitude',
        'text',
        array(
            'label' => $translator->trans( 'project.longitude' ),
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'class'=> 'form-control',
                'value' => call_user_func( function() use ( $city, $em ){
                    if( $city instanceof City ){
                        return $city->getLongitude();
                    }
                    else{
                        $repository = $em->getRepository( 'AppBundle:City' );
                        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder( 'city' );

                        if( is_numeric( $city ) ){
                            $query->where( 'city.id = :city' )
                                ->setParameter( 'city', $city );
                        }
                        else{
                            $query->where( 'city.id = 2715' );
                        }

                        $city = $query->getQuery()->getSingleResult();

                        return $city->getLongitude();
                    }
                })
            )
        )
    );
};
```

$translator and $em vars are passed from the controller to form builder, then to event listeners, then to $refreshLongitude function